# How to record audio playing on headset

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, recording, audio-recording, screen-recorder

I'm trying to record screen +microphone+ system audio output. I tried below cmd but it records only screen, headset microphone but not the system audio output i'm hearing on the headset

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="Headset Microphone (Plantronics C320-M)" record_%date:~-2,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%_%time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%.mp4
```

If I don't connect headset it records all the three Screen, Laptop microphone, Laptop Audio. I tried below command when headset is not connected

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mix (Conexant ISST Audio)" record_%date:~-2,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%_%time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%.mp4
```

Can anyone please help me here in recording audio output on connected headset

Edit: using windows os

Comment: If you are running Pulseaudio, record from the `.monitor` source of your headset sink. Use `pavucontrol` to have a look. There's several similar questions about this here, search a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on MacOS you can record microphone and system audio via `ffmpeg` by creating an aggregate device — using the awesome and free `Blackhole` virtual audio driver that allows applications to pass audio to other applications with zero additional latency.

https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole