# can't record screen using ffmpeg, including microphone and bluetooth headset audio, in sync

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, bluetooth

I'm trying to record my screen using `ffmpeg`, but including the audio from the computer microphone and the computer audio (the one I hear for my bluetooth headset). I can get the file with this command:

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 24 -f x11grab -i :1.0+0,0 -f pulse -ac 2 -i $(pactl list short sources | grep -i "alsa_input" | awk '{print $2}') -f pulse -i $(pactl list short sources | grep -i "blue" | awk '{print $2}') -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -ac 2 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset fast -c:a aac -b:a 192k -strict experimental file.mp4
```

but the audio of both inputs is out of sync. Specifically, the computer audio in out of sync.

These are my attempts for fixing this:

```
#no bluetooth
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 24 -f x11grab -i :1.0+0,0 -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -acodec aac -strict experimental file.mp4

#no bluetooth 
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 24 -f x11grab -i :1.0+0,0 -f pulse -i default -acodec aac -strict experimental file.mp4

#v5 only audio but out of sync
ffmpeg -f pulse -ac 2 -i $(pactl list short sources | grep -i "alsa_input" | awk '{print $2}') -f pulse -i $(pactl list short sources | grep -i "blue" | awk '{print $2}') -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 -c:a aac -b:a 192k file.aac
```

any suggestions?

I'm in ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Have you tried OBS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29479551

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1423215/1482432

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1560066/1482432 but use Pulseaudio for audio loopback

Comment: Just use [screenapp.io](https://screenapp.io/) instead.

Comment: With your commands above, this is with a Bluetooth headset and not a laptop microphone? I haven't attempted, but I only have a laptop with a microphone that I could possibly attempt with your efforts.